# How do I view all pending push notifications with react native on Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, react-native, android-push-notification

How do you view all notifications stored currently on an Android device with react native? I can find all pending notifications stored on an iOS device but not Android. On iOS i can use 'PushNotificationIOS.getScheduledLocalNotifications()' and get back an array of objects showing all pending notifications including an id for each notification. I can't figure out how to do this on Android. Can anyone help with this...? I'm using [Zo0r's package 'react-native-push-notifications'](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) to create push notifications on the device.

Just to be clear, I can create push notifications just fine. They work great. What I want to do is view what notifications are stored on the device so I can create a dynamic message on a scheduled event saying that this event has a push notification stored to alert the user 15 minutes before the event starts.